# How do I generate a high frequency sine wave using a PLL? 900 to 950 MHz

Tags: pll, vco

I know of a few ways to generate a sine wave; Op-amps, 555, LC, crystals, or microcontrollers. But none of those would really work for a frequency as high as 900 MHz. I have heard of phase lock loops, but I don't know how to use one. What's the highest factor I could multiply my reference frequency by and still have it end up with the expected output frequency, and how do I divide the frequency leaving the VCO? Is a VCO part of the PLL or are they separate components? Will my output be a sine wave if my reference frequency is a sine wave, or do these only output square waves?

Comment: A PLL **locks** a high frequency to a low frequency reference. It is usefull if you need a **precise** high frequency. I do not think you need a PLL. You can make a simple 900 MHz oscillator based on a single transistor. But this is RF design, you **must** know what you're doing to be succesfull. So study how others make 900 MHz oscillators and try to do the same.

Comment: I would like to attempt to make a radio transmitter in the ISM band. It's not vital to have a specific frequency as long as it wont drift around. Don't worry about me failing, that's mostly what I expect from a first attempt anyway

Comment: There are PLL ICs that can make a 900 MHz sinewave. Analog Devices and Texas Instruments make them. These are complex ICs, if you needed these then you would know how to use them. If you want to start with PLLs, get a 4046 PLL-IC. It's very cheap and easy to use and teaches you the basics of PLLs. It can only go up to a few MHz though.

Comment: You can make a low-drift single transistor oscillator if you use a resonator to determine the frequency. Many 433 MHz transmitters use this, see: http://www.freeinfosociety.com/electronics/schemview.php?id=1837

Comment: OK but attempting to do the impossible is a waste of time and teaches you little. Setting a goal which **IS** achievable is less frustrating and more rewarding.

Comment: That is orders of magnitude simpler that my original plan, thank you! I'll step down to stuff more my speed. Would this 433 MHz schematic be modifiable to operate at 900 MHz?

Comment: If you had a 900 MHz resonator and a transistor that has enough gain at 900 MHz: YES. But why insist on 900 MHz ? The 433 MHz band can be used without a license in most countries. In some you can use 315 MHz. Are you sure you are allowed to use 900 MHz because that is used for GSM by many countries.

Comment: OK, in North and South America you can use 902 MHz - 932 MHz.

Comment: That 902-932 band, plus I already have a giant 900 MHz antenna lying around. I think 433 MHz is known as the "family band" and I know It's very well filled in my location. I live at a giant ski resort where they use radios for everything and I'd rather not interfere. But if I need to buy a new antenna, it would be a lot easier to work with a lower frequency

Comment: @FakeMoustache:  The bit about the 4046 reminds me of a two-way radio that was manufactured for the German police.  It actually did use a synthesizer built around a 4046 - it divided the 2M frequency (around 170MHz) down to 5kHz for the 4046.  It worked well enough for voice, but had a 5kHz whine that had to be filtered out of the receive audio.  I learned this the hard way when a voice frequency inverter (fixed frequency scrambler) was installed in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use a simple single-chip transmitter designed for the 902-928 MHz ISM band. Here is a typical circuit:

[image]

This [chip](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX2900-MAX2904.pdf) uses a PLL and internal divider to lock to a reference crystal. Power output is +23dBm (200mW) and it does not require a uC to set it up.

There are a number of app notes and a somewhat pricey eval board available from the supplier.

In answer to your question about a minimum comparison frequency for a PLL, there is no minimum, but the loop filter frequency and the lock-in time will increase proportionally to the inverse of the comparison frequency (all other things being equal), so if you compare at 100Hz vs. 10MHz it will take 100,000 times as long to lock in and stabilize.